# How do you show a function is continuous at endpoints if the domain is disjoint closed intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

I was given the following:

The function $f(x)=−1$ for $x\in[−1,0]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(1,2]$, with domain $[−1,0]\cup(1,2]$ is continuous everywhere.

The function $f(x)=−1$ for $x\in[−1,0]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(0,2]$, with domain $ [−1,2]$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$.

The second example makes sense because at $x=0$, the two sided limits are not equal. But what about at $x=0$ for the first example? How do you use the epsilon-delta definition to prove $x=0$ is continuous if there are no open intervals around that point?

Answer (score 1):

Continuity is defined with respect to the function's domain: $f$ is continuous at $a$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that *for all $x \in \text{dom}(f)$*, if $|x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

The fact that $f$ is not defined on $(0,1]$ does not interfere with showing $f$ is continuous at $0$:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be an arbitrary value, and set $\delta = \frac 12$. If $|x - 0| < \delta$ and $x \in \text{dom}(f)$, then $x \in (-\frac 12, 0]$, so $f(x) = -1 = f(0)$. Hence $|f(x) - f(0)| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Since the choices of $\epsilon$ and $x$ are arbitrary within their given conditions, this calculation holds for all such values. Thus the definition of continuity is satisfied, and $f$ is continuous at $0$.